# Power BI - Change node color in a network navigator chart

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I've created a network navigator chart with the node colors as `Green`(#67D4CC). It works fine on my Power BI desktop(2.88.1682.0 64-bit ). However, after publishing the report onto the web version , the nodes inside the network chart changes to `Black` color automatically.

Is there a way to change this on web version? Any clues will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using Google Chrome as a workaround was proved effective for the same issue for another user. MSFT had acknowledged to report this problem internally then.

Reference: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/Network-Navigator-Colors/m-p/237925

So try using any different browser just in case. I couldn't find any tracking item for this now, you can go ahead and raise a new issue here https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-NetworkNavigator/issues

Comment: Thanks @KarthikBhyresh-MT.  I've tried openining in Google Chrome, it doesn't seem to work. I will probably raise a new issue.

Comment: New issue raised - https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-NetworkNavigator/issues/48